# How can I reduce the size of bundled Unity DLLs on Android?

Tags: unity, android

I have created a simple project (I am a Unity beginner) for Android but the apk size is around 18 MB!

I checked the documentation. One way to decrease the apk size is to check the editor log. Then I discovered that imported DLLs have a size of 3.9MB.

I only used UnityEngine and Collision packages. So how can I avoid to import the other big DLLs?

Comment: Which .NET API Compatibility Level are you currently using? [Switching from .NET 2.0 to .NET 2.0 Subset](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) omits some libraries and can reduce the size of the build.

Comment: http://www.unityrealm.com/how-to-reduce-apk-size-in-unity-5/